# If Else Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am writing if else expression in SSRS like that

=IIF((Parameters!piStartDate.Value = "" and Parameters!piEndDate.Value = ""), "UnExtracted ACH Records","ACH Extracted Record")

Its working for first condition and giving error for second condition. Can any one point out mistake i am making.

Comment: What are all the other possible logical outcomes?   Why do you have a second IIF() if you only want one of the two results?

Comment: I need two results if value is null then UnExtracted ACH Records else ACH Extracted Record. But i want to check two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same condition two time having same parameter 'piStartDate'
Try below

=IIF((Parameters!piStartDate.Value = "") and (Parameters!piEndDate.Value = ""), "UnExtracted ACH     Records","ACH Extracted Record")

It will work fine.

Comment: =IIF((Parameters!piStartDate.Value = "") and (Parameters!piEndDate.Value = ""), "UnExtracted ACH Records","ACH Extracted Record")

Answer (score 0):

Many problems.

1st you say you want to check two parameters, but you are only checking the same parameter twice.  Both IIF() functions are checking piStartDate.

2nd, in the conditional part of an IIF, you need to write out "AND" instead of "&".   So your second example should be:

```
=IIF(Parameters!piStartDate.Value = "" AND Parameters!piStartDate.Value = "", "UnExtracted ACH Records","ACH Extracted Record")
```

3rd, you're not checking for NULL, you're checking for empty strings, but maybe that's just what you really meant.

Comment: Sorry it was piEndDate.

Comment: But still i am getting error when these two  are not empty

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!piStartDate.Value) AND IsNothing(Parameters!piEndDate.Value), "UnExtracted ACH Records","ACH Extracted Record")
```

Isn't the same ask for null that "". In your Report go to property from these Parameter and check the option allow blank value and now your first conditional should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the expression like that and it worked for me. Thanks every one for your help.

=IIF(Parameters!piStartDate.Value & Parameters!piEndDate.Value = "", "UnExtracted ACH Records","ACH Extracted Record")